# Get the id of one of the many elements with the same class which reached the top

Tags: javascript

My HTML is something like

```html
<div id='the-div'>

<span class='mspage' id='id1'>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</span>
<span class='mspage' id='id2'>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</span>
<span class='mspage' id='id3'> ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</span>
</div>
```

The css sets `display:block` to all `span`s.

The `id`s are generated on the fly by some other code so I don't know them in advance. The `<div>` is a scrollable one, and I'd like to get the `id` of a `span` with `class=mspage` when it reaches the top of the `<div>`.

```
document.getElementById('the-div').addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    
    let position = this.scrollTop <-- this gives me the current position
    pseudocode: if a span with class=mspage has scrollTop value of 0, then get its id

  })
```

This is my attempt at a reproducible example, it's the first time I do it so please bear with me.

```js
document.getElementById('the-div').addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    const el = document.elementFromPoint(0, this.getBoundingClientRect().y);
    if (el && el.classList.contains("mspage")) {
        console.log('found')
    }
    else { console.log(el)}
});
```

```css
#xslt-transformation {

overflow: auto;

}

.line {
  display: block;
}

.line-group {
  padding: 2rem;
}

#container {
height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:gray;padding-top:300px;">
    <div id="the-div" style="background:white;height:200px; overflow-y: scroll">
                                        
            <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 002"></span>    
        
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line"><del>Latha gan raibh Padric 'na * Mhùr</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>Cha raibh sailm air ùidh, ach ceol.</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>Chaidh è thigh Oissain Mhic Fhinn,</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>O sann leis bu bhinn a ghloir.</del></span>
            </span>
         
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Failt ort fein, a shean-fhir shuairc,</span>
               <span class="line">Air chuairt thugad thainig mi,</span>
            
            <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 003"></span>
            
               <span class="line">A laoich mhòir <span>***</span> mhìlidh nach meat</span>
               <span class="line">Cha d' eur thu riamh neach mu d'ni.</span>

            </span>
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Sgeul a b'ait leom fhaotainn uait</span>

            </span>

            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Dh'innsinn sin duitse gun dàil,</span>

            </span>

            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Dearmad air † fleadh a rinn Fionn</span>
               <span class="line">Ann  Albuinn ri h àm nan laoch, </span>  
               
       
               <span class="footnotes">Footnotes: * Lùth-chuirt †cuirm, fèisd</span>
               <span class="catchword">Chuir</span>
               
               <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 004"></span>
               
               <span class="pagenum">4</span>
               
               <span class="line">Chuir pairt do'n Fheinn fui' struim dearg,</span>
               <span class="line">Dh'eirich orra fearg is fraoch</span>
            </span>
            

      </div>
      </div>
```

### Update

This is my attempt at using `IntersectionObserver`, for now it's not outputting anything. Am I going in the right direction?

```js
let observerOptions = {
    root: document.getElementById('test'),
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.5
}

const images = document.querySelectorAll('.mspage')

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
  console.dir('intersecting' + entry)
  })
})

images.forEach(image => {
observer.observe(image)
})
```

```css
#the-div {

overflow: auto;

}

.line {
  display: block;
}

.line-group {
  padding: 2rem;
}

#container {
height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:gray;padding-top:300px;">
    <div id="the-div" style="background:white;height:200px; overflow-y: scroll">
            <div id="test" style="position: sticky;height: 1px;visibility: hidden;"></div>
            
            <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 002"></span>    
        
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line"><del>Latha gan raibh Padric 'na * Mhùr</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>Cha raibh sailm air ùidh, ach ceol.</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>Chaidh è thigh Oissain Mhic Fhinn,</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>O sann leis bu bhinn a ghloir.</del></span>
            </span>
         
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Failt ort fein, a shean-fhir shuairc,</span>
               <span class="line">Air chuairt thugad thainig mi,</span>
            
            <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 003"></span>
            
               <span class="line">A laoich mhòir <span>***</span> mhìlidh nach meat</span>
               <span class="line">Cha d' eur thu riamh neach mu d'ni.</span>

            </span>
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Sgeul a b'ait leom fhaotainn uait</span>

            </span>

            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Dh'innsinn sin duitse gun dàil,</span>

            </span>

            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Dearmad air † fleadh a rinn Fionn</span>
               <span class="line">Ann  Albuinn ri h àm nan laoch, </span>  
               
       
               <span class="footnotes">Footnotes: * Lùth-chuirt †cuirm, fèisd</span>
               <span class="catchword">Chuir</span>
               
               <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 004"></span>
               
               <span class="pagenum">4</span>
               
               <span class="line">Chuir pairt do'n Fheinn fui' struim dearg,</span>
               <span class="line">Dh'eirich orra fearg is fraoch</span>
            </span>
            

      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder They get some minimal styling from css, like padding and margins. They are filled with text of course, I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: No, the css also sets `display: block` :) - good point though, I'll add that as well.

Comment: `#the-div` doesn't seem to be scrolling, it's stretched to fit the whole content

Comment: I've edited now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know they'll be the topmost element, you could use [`elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint). For instance, if the elements are at the left-hand edge:

```
document.getElementById('the-div').addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    const el = document.elementFromPoint(0, this.getBoundingClientRect().y);
    if (el && el.classList.contains("mspage")) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

```js
let lastId = null;
document.getElementById('the-div').addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    const el = document.elementFromPoint(0, this.getBoundingClientRect().y);
    if (el && el.classList.contains("mspage")) {
        const {id} = el;
        if (id !== lastId) {
            console.log(el.id);
            lastId = id;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#the-div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.mspage {
    display: block;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.unrelated {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="unrelated">Something unrelated</div>
<div id='the-div'>
<span class='mspage' id='id1'></span>
<span class='mspage' id='id2'></span>
<span class='mspage' id='id3'></span>
<span class='mspage' id='id4'></span>
<span class='mspage' id='id5'></span>
</div>
```

The reason for `this.getBoundingClientRect().y` as the `y` coordinate is that you've said `#the-div` isn't at the top of the page, so it may be in the middle of the viewport, but you need to see the scrolling of the `.mspage` spans within `#the-div`. `elementFromPoint` takes viewport (not document or element) coordinates, so we need to know where the top of `#the-div` is relative to the viewport — which is exactly what [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) tells us. (Thank you, [@skara9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17055403/skara9), for pitching in with that when that requirement came to light.)

Alternatively, you might use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this: Put a one pixel high invisible element at the top of `#the-div` (`position: sticky`) and watch for intersections with these `.mspage` elements. If the elements are inline, that will probably be more reliable.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is useful. Complication: my `<div>` is somewhere in the middle of the page, so, sadly, `document.elementFromPoint(0, 0);` doesn't work for me. Shall I go down the `IntersectionObserver` route then?

Comment: @HBMCS just replace that second `0` with the y pos - see my edit

Comment: @HBMCS - The spans scroll within `#the-div`? (I think so from your question edit.) If so, then skara9 is right. If not, would you update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the precise situation using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button)? [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Thank you for all the information, I had a go at creating a snippet, let me know if it's OK.

Comment: @HBMCS - The snippet has `#the-div` at the top of the viewport, and doesn't do any scrolling. From your description of the situation originally, I think the above should work in your real use case, but only if the spans scroll *within* `#the-div` (which you did say they did at one point).

Comment: I did put a container, perhaps you got an earlier version, I edited a few minutes ago.

Comment: @HBMCS - And in that, the *container* scrolls, not the contents of `#the-div`. Which is it really?

Comment: Sorry, I edited again - any better?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder After all I think using the `IntersectionObserver` would be a better and more precise option anyway. I've updated my question with an attempt of implementing it, which as yet doesn't work.